# How to get 2 DoF inverted pendulum degree?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, robotics

I have a project about 2-DoF inverted pendulum using joystick (X-Y degree value) sensor and holonomic robot. Because the inverted pendulum able to move in X-Y planes, I need to get $\theta$ from $\alpha$ degree and $\beta$. I've try the following equation from paper with the similar topic.

[inverted pendulum visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1je2.png)

$tan^2\theta = tan^2\alpha + tan^2\beta$

with $\alpha = 30^o$ and $\beta = 30^o$,

then I get result $\theta = 1.46085^o$

My question is, am I do it wrong because what I need is the degree value and the result seems to small for combination of two $30^o$ X-YDegree?

can somebody explain to me how to get the right angle value?

Comment: Looks to me like your `tan` and `atan` functions work in radians but you’re giving them values in degrees and interpreting the result in degrees instead.

Comment: That's work, thanks @amd for mentioned the radian value. I really forgot about that.